# How can I make an oblique rectangle shape for wooden line braces?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How can I make the shape, pointed at with the yellow arrow?

This is actually an image from a tutorial. I am trying to make this whole framework, for now, I am just trying to make a shape that looks like the one I am pointing at with the arrow. So basically this rectangle shape where the faces are sort of rotated away from each other.

As you can see this sort of oblique shape is quite common in the whole wood framework.

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to see exactly what you're trying to do without more images. You seem to have odd vertices selected all over your model in your image. If you could explain precisely what you're trying to achieve and maybe share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there we might be able to help.

Comment: This is actually an image from a tutorial. So in the end I am trying to make this whole framework. For now, I am just trying to make a shape that looks like the one I am pointing at with the arrow. So basically this rectangle shape where the faces are sort of rotated away from each other.

Comment: I am going to copy that comment to the question, because it is essential information for people to be able to understand what you are asking. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you for that! I should have made it more clear

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282335/35559) might be relevant. There might be a less fiddly way.. still waiting for it :)

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit Mode* scale a cube on one axis, then select one of the non-square faces, and further scale it on the same axis:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have more complex geometry like bevelled edges or something like that, you can also use the Shear operator. You can search for it with search menu(F3), it's in Mesh -> Transform menu and the hotkey is Shift+Ctrl+Alt+S

[image]

It's a bit weird, because it works with screen space coordinates X(width) and Y(height), so you need to look at the model from the side(like I enter "Front Orthographic" view with Numpad 1 in the example) and press Y or X to constrain operation axis. Numerical input works during operation with it so you can hit 1 for full 45 degree corner and -, or -1 from the start if you want it in the other direction, or you could also enter any other float value:

[image]

Like I mentioned in the comments, shear is transform operation so transform pivot point settings define the point it originates from. In the example below you can see me set the transform pivot point to 3d cursor and snap the 3d cursor to a vertex point. It doesn't need to be 3d cursor, it could be any of the options - for example you could use active element as the transform pivot point and simply select your chosen vertex or edge last to make it active and achieve exactly same result.

[image]

I often use shear to make various frames, windows, profiles, ceiling mouldings and what not and I find myself in situations where I need to zoom out and zoom in to see where the next corner is so it's often convenient to not worry about it at first but later snap the geometry to something else in the scene so that's another option - you can just move or snap it in place where you need it after the operation.

Comment: That works great! But how can I make sure it keeps the edges the same size? When I shear like this, my 'square' face becomes rectangular. I want to keep all the sides the same size.

Comment: Shear is transform operation and transform pivot point settings work with it so you can define the transform pivot point as with any other transform operation like scale and rotate. I'll update the answer with explanation in a few minutes.