# Is it possible to connect two planes to create a oblique shape?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to create a oblique shape as can be seen in the first picture.

Is it possible to do this by connecting two planes? I have placed the planes where I want them to be, as can be seen in the second picture.

I have tried creating an oblique shape by using shear or scaling one face, as was mentioned in this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284025/how-can-i-make-an-oblique-rectangle-shape-for-wooden-line-braces/284039#284039)
But when I try these options, the shape of my square changes into a rectangle. I want all sides to be equal.
So is it possible to 'just' connect two planes together?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it has to be 2 separate Plane meshes, because you can achieve this if the planes are in the same mesh with Bridge Edge Loop https://imgur.com/a/oR3rGnF

Comment: It looks from the image as if it's all made from a single mesh while you're starting by adding new objects in Object mode. As @Emir says, you can use Bridge edge loops if both planes are added to your original object in Edit mode. You can also use loop cuts on the upright to create the mounting for the angled strut and then bridge from those to the plane on the ground to create the strut. You would have to adjust the scale afterwards to get the shape correct though.